# Count wordpress posts wth specific category and meta value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to know the amount of posts for a given category and meta_values. I dont want to use get posts because that actually retrieves an array of posts objects and i only need to know the amount of posts, i don't need all the overhead of the posts array (the results may be in the order of thousands).

These are the conditions that need to be met:

-Category is "user_stats"

AND

-Meta_key is "start_time" and meta_value is bigger than "y" and smaller than "z"
("y" and "z" are integers)

AND

-Meta_key  is "seller_id" and meta_value is "123456778"

What i need is the sql statement to execute it with (the code below doesn't work):

```
$sql_statements="SELECT count(DISTINCT wp_postmeta.`post_id`) 
  FROM wp_posts
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = 
wp_term_relationships.object_id)
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
= wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
 WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key        = 'seller_nickname'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value    >= '1523656442'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value    <= '1523656529')";

$query = $wpdb->get_results($sql_statements);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about it "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Btw, wp_postmeta is an inner join. Is that what you want?

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/fpHFSrZa).